# Python tornado AsyncHttpClient does not send any request

Tags: python, tornado

Below is a snippet from the tornado [documentation](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpclient.html#http-client-interfaces).

```
def handle_response(response):
if response.error:
    print("Error: %s" % response.error)
else:
    print(response.body)

http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
http_client.fetch("http://www.google.com/", handle_response)
```

But this does not print anything to the console. I tried adding a `time.sleep` at the end but even then nothing prints.

Also, it does not send any request to my server when I change the url above to point to my server. 
`tornado.httpclient.HTTPClient` works fine though.

I am on Macbook with Python 3.6.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tornado is an asynchronous framework where all tasks are scheduled by a single event loop called the IOLoop. At the end of your program, put:

```
import tornado.ioloop
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

That will start the loop running and allow the AsyncHTTPClient to fetch the URL.

The IOLoop runs forever, so you need to implement some logic that determines when to call `IOLoop.stop()`. In your example program, call `IOLoop.stop()` at the bottom of `handle_response`. In a real HTTP client program, the loop should run until all work is complete and the program is ready to exit.